# Binding WPF Control Name to different Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Have style for a series of buttons btn1, btn2, btn3, etc.

Inside the style for each button is a TextBlock for displaying the "Content" of the button, (since the border inside the style covers any content of the button itself).

Now, I would like for the TextBlock name to be tied to the button name.  For example - btn1's text block's name would be btn1Txt. The purpose of this would be the end user can assign each button its own text in a settings menu.

Any hints on how I would go about this?  I admit I'm relatively new to WPF and bindings.

> EDIT::::  WHAT I"VE GOT SO FAR THAT IS WORKING.

On load, the program checks the settings file for the Text for each button.  Each button's content is assigned the proper information.  Then inside the style, I bind the TextBlock Text to the content of the parent button.

This may not be the normal way of going about it, but it works

Method

```
List<string> MainButtons = Properties.Settings.Default.MainButtonNames.Cast<string>().ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < MainButtons.Count(); i++)
        {
            string actualNum = Convert.ToString((i + 1));
            var MainButtonFinder = (Button)this.FindName("MainButton" + actualNum);
            Console.WriteLine(MainButtonFinder.Name);
            MainButtonFinder.Content = MainButtons[i];
            Console.WriteLine(MainButtonFinder.Content);
        }
```

Style

```
<Style x:Key="MainButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100px"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="20" Height="45" Width="100" Margin="0" Background="#FF99CCFF">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="LCARS" Foreground="White" Padding="5px" FontSize="18px" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you want is to modify the "text" of the button, it occurs to me that you can do it this way.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ButtonTest, Path=Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
    <Button Name="ButtonTest" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Height="40">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is closest to what I actually found that works.  I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to go about what you're trying to do. Here's the "right" way to do it. There's a fair amount of boilerplate code here, but you get used to it.

Write a button viewmodel and give your main viewmodel an ObservableCollection of those:

```
#region ViewModelBase Class
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
#endregion ViewModelBase Class

#region MainViewModel Class
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ButtonItems.Add(new ButtonItemViewModel("First Command", "First Item", () => MessageBox.Show("First Item Executed")));
        ButtonItems.Add(new ButtonItemViewModel("Second Command", "Second Item", () => MessageBox.Show("Second Item Executed")));
    }

    #region ButtonItems Property
    public ObservableCollection<ButtonItemViewModel> ButtonItems { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ButtonItemViewModel>();
    #endregion ButtonItems Property

}
#endregion MainViewModel Class

#region ButtonItemViewModel Class
public class ButtonItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ButtonItemViewModel(String cmdName, String text, Action cmdAction)
    {
        CommandName = cmdName;
        Text = text;

        Command = new DelegateCommand(cmdAction);
    }

    #region Text Property
    private String _text = default(String);
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Text Property


    #region CommandName Property
    private String _commandName = default(String);
    public String CommandName
    {
        get { return _commandName; }
        private set
        {
            if (value != _commandName)
            {
                _commandName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion CommandName Property

    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }
}
#endregion ButtonItemViewModel Class

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    private Action _action;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Make that `MainViewModel` the `DataContext` of your Window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

And here's how you can put it all together in the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox Header="Buttons">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            Margin="2"
                            MinWidth="80"
                            Content="{Binding Text}"
                            Command="{Binding Command}"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Edit Buttons">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListBox 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="2"
                    x:Name="ButtonEditorListBox"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonItems}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Text="{Binding CommandName}"
                                    />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat=': &quot;{0}&quot;'}"
                                    />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <ContentControl 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="8,2,2,2"
                    Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ButtonEditorListBox}"
                    >
                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Margin="2"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Text="{Binding CommandName, StringFormat={}{0}: }"
                                    />
                                <TextBox
                                    Margin="2"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Back to your question:

> Inside the style for each button is a TextBlock for displaying the "Content" of the button, (since the border inside the style covers any content of the button itself).

You're doing styles wrong. Very, very wrong. I can help you fix it if you show me the style.